# Save/Load problems with SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

and sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm learning to use SharedPreferences and I have a bit of a problem: 
I'm using this code to save to SharedPreferences:

```
public void saveInMemory(String[] saveThis){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OIBListActivity.this);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    for (int i = 0; i < saveThis.length; i++) {
        sb.append(saveThis[i]);
        sb.append(";");
    }
    editor.putString("listaOIB", sb.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

And this code to load saved values:

```
public String loadFromMemory(String id){
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OIBListActivity.this);
    return prefs.getString(id, "NOPREFSAVED");
}
```

I've also already declared prefs and editor outside, so that shouldnt be a problem:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Now, **my problem is that when I enter this activity and save files that i received from other activity(via putExtra, if that helps), then proceed to load it everything works fine.**
**Then I reenter my activity without sending any files to it (from other activity) and try to use *loadFromMemory()* and it doesnt work.** My understanding is that it should have saved files when I entered Activity for the first time, and then load it whenever I want.

Any help?

Comment: Your understanting is correct, can we see where you call your loadFromMemory method, maybe the problem is with the "id" String

Comment: Are you passing same id every time to loadFromMemory()

Comment: I'm passing the same id:
String loadaniPodaci = loadFromMemory("listaOIB");

That line I use to load from SharedPrefs

Comment: By the way, you should keep `prefs` and `editor` local method variables. Augmenting the scope of variables is source of errors when not needed.

Comment: I used them as local method variables, then thought that was the source of problem. I will return it the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

add the method and call when you add and other is call when you get

//this method is call when you add the data

```
    public static void setAlarmHourTime(String value, Activity activity) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor pref = activity.getSharedPreferences("ALARMHOURTIME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    pref.putString("alarmhourtime", value);
    pref.commit();
}
```

//this method is call when you retrive the data

```
public static String getAlarmHourTime(Activity activity) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("ALARMHOURTIME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString("alarmhourtime","7");

}
```

Comment: Tried it, still is not working if i don't call setAlarmHourTime() every time before calling getAlarmHourTime().

By the way im calling your methods like this in my OnCreate():
String loadaniPodaci = getAlarmHourTime(this);

If im doing it wrong maybe that is the error, but it works when I set it first.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I already added the data first time when I entered activity, and second time I enter i just want to load that data. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: ya i understand.  so when you enter first the add data.. and check when you enter second time then don't add the data only get data.. set login to add 1 time data..

Comment: Already doing that, when there is no data to add I just use loadFromMemory();

Comment: SharedPreferences add only string and Int data.. the you convert your StringBuilder  to string then add. I thing this is problem.

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem, as it is working right when saving it first.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retrieve content saved in `editor.putString("listaOIB", sb.toString());`, then the id you pass in `loadFromMemory` should be "listaOIB".
Is it the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case :)

Comment: Then you need to provide a bit more code or context. When is your save method called for example?

Comment: This would be my code to check if send the right element (noviOib), if it has size 11 then save it in memory, else just proceed on to load what was saved last time.

Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
String oib= args.getString("noviOib");
..
if(!(oib.length()<11)){
..
noviOIBPostoji=1;
}else{
noviOIBPostoji=0;
}
..
if(noviOIBPostoji==1) {
..
saveInMemory(SviPodaciString);
}
String loadaniPodaci = loadFromMemory("listaOIB");
...